# C# Determine 20% of a dollar amount, result as decimal

Tags: c#

Need help converting the result to a decimal.

I need to determine 20% of a dollar amount so that I can compare it to another amount to find the larger of the two. Easy stuff but I am struggling with getting the result to a decimal format.

I have so far...

```
double foo = (.20 / 100) * 326.23;
```

the above expression gives me 0.65246
but what I need is the dollar amount or decimal 65.246 .

whats the next step?

Comment: just leave out the /100 it's **percent** after all - you also should add the homework tag

Comment: Why don't you just multiple by 0.2???

Comment: When using financial data or values that need base 10 precision, use the appropriate type for the job: `decimal`. Don't use `float` or `double` when dealing with dollars and cents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things; one as another answer says you just multiple by .2.  The second is that for monetary amounts you should use the actual type `decimal`, not `double`, as you'll never be able to get exact amounts out of `double`.

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing by .2 by 100.

You should simply multiple `0.2 * 326.23`.

Answer (score 2):

You're removing the 100 from the number twice, first in converting 20% to .20 and then once again with the /100.  Of course you get a number 100x as small as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

the next step to reach 65.246 from `double foo = (.20 / 100) * 326.23;` is multipliying it with 100, well but I am not very good at [math](http://www.google.com.tr/#hl=tr&biw=1366&bih=679&q=what+is+math?&oq=what%2bis%2bmath?&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=9358l9358l0l1l1l0l0l0l0l222l222l2-1&fp=e145f08b19119b86).